# Shemona Ushloshim Umeya - mi yodeya?

Tags: mi-yodeya-series, number

### Who knows one hundred thirty-eight?

*Please cite/link your sources, if possible. At some point at least twenty-four hours from now, I will:*

- *Upvote all interesting answers.*
- *Accept the best answer.*
- *Go on to the next number.*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

138 is the gematria of צמח and מנחם, two names of Moshiach (see Ibn Ezra to Zech. 3:8 - appropriately for the season, part of the haftarah of Shabbos Chanukah).

Answer (score 2):

138 CE: death of Hadrian, שחיק טמיא

Answer (score 1):

138 OPENINGS OF WISDOM was written by Ramchal

Answer (score 0):

138 = gematria of the word "chametz".

Comment: Is this significant?

Comment: @DoubleAA, it is to Yaacov. Doesn't make it interesting to anyone else, but not reason to make fun.

Comment: @SethJ Not making fun. Challenging its identity as an answer.

Comment: @DoubleAA [ahem](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/4378/5)

Comment: @SethJ Two traditional names of the Mashiach with the same Gematria? That's significant (ish. At least it claims to be).

Comment: Up voted due to my answer

Answer (score 0):

138 years were the Angels banned from heaven until Yaakovs dream for saying (to Lot) "we are destroying this place". Midrash Rabbah Vayeira

To Yaakovs answer I find chametz as "extra" or "superfluous" like the angels response and absence of Hashem. Also the destruction came during Pesach.

Also day 3 and day 4 of Bereshis are 69 words (138 total).